# Difference between `ls -d */` and `ls -d *`?

Tags: ls

I am struggling to understand how ls -d works. I've read through the other ls -d questions but none of them ask why `ls -d *` doesn't work the same way as `ls -d */`. Why is the separator character at the end so important?

`ls *` and `ls */` behave the same way, so I was expecting `ls -d *` and `ls -d */` to work the same way as well.

Instead,
`ls -d *` lists all files in current directory just like doing `ls`, whereas `ls -d */` lists the directory in the current directory. Why is this so?

Answer (score 4):

> `ls *` and `ls */` behave the same way.

No, they don't. If you have files in your working directory, they will be listed with the first command, but not the second.

`ls` will list the files and directories (including their content) passed on the command line. If you use shell globbing your shell will replace the [patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) "with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames" (c.f. [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)).

The pattern `*` will match every file and directory in the current directory (excluding hidden files starting with `.`), while `*/` will only match directories (excluding hidden directories).

The switch `-d` disables the listing of contents for directories but files passed to ls will still get listed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: the ending `/` forces ls to only look at directories.

Please note that behaviour is consistent (with and without `-d`).

A small test:

```
mkdir /tmp/test
touch /tmp/test/a
mkdir /tmp/test/b
touch /tmp/test/b/c
cd /tmp/test
```

And then do `ls *`and `ls */` and you will notice the difference.